# Using 2 drives as 1 centOS

Tags: centos

I have a dedicated server that has 2 SSD at 120GB each I want to make 1 partition for the whole server and have those 2 drives work like 1 so I basically have 240GB, How do I do this? If it helps you answer this I'm using ovh to host it. CentOS 6.4 64bit.

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb

       Device Boot    Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1   *         1        2550    20478976   fd  Linux raid autodetect
    /dev/sdb2          2550        2615      523264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sdb3          2615       14593    96211968   fd  Linux raid autodetect
    /dev/sdb4         14593       14593        2016+  83  Linux

    Disk /dev/md3: 98.5 GB, 98520989696 bytes
    2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 24052976 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000


    Disk /dev/md1: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes
    2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5119728 cylinders
    Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Comment: When I do "fdisk -l" I get this http://pastebin.com/vNhAyKWb where do I go from here to get the 240GB and 1 partition? @justbrowsing

Answer (score 0):

Using RAID 0 mode, however it's a very bad idea, if one of them dies, you lose all the data on both.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-s390info-raid.html
 << the proper way for CentOS

Answer (score -1):

A couple options.

1. Put the drives in [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid_0#RAID_0). Do you have a RAID card and/or hardware RAID support on the motherboard? Otherwise you'll have to do a [software RAID](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-raid-config.html). (Recommended)
2. Install on one drive and create a mountpoint for the second drive to `/usr` for example. (Legacy)